# I need a formula to calculate the difference between two cells retyrn a blank cell if one of the 2 cells is blank?

Tags: excel, formula

Example: A2 = 4, C2 = 2; it would calculate the difference to be 2 but i need it to show blank if C2 were empty instead

Comment: Something like `=if(C2="","",A2-C2)`?

Comment: Isn't there also a cell formatting setting to display zero cells as blank?

Comment: Do you want to check if one of them is blank or just C2 is blank?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `IF`.

Usage: `IF(condition, execute_if_true, execute_if_false)`

So, we want to first see if C2 is blank. `IF(C2="", execute_if_true, execute_if_false)`

return blank if C2 is blank: `IF(C2="", "", execute_if_false)`

otherwise, return the difference between A2 and C2: `IF(C2="", "", A2-C2)`

Comment: + 1 Nicely explained :)

Comment: Thanks! Works great for the blank cell part but does something odd when both cells have a #. A2 has 19,138 and C2 has 16,404 and it ruturned -16,323. Not sure what I did wrong there.

Comment: @user2271703 I don't get that issue if I put 19,138 in cell A2 and 16404 in cell C2... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can test many logical conditions inside OR function:

=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A2);ISBLANK(C2));"";A2-C2)